# use Junit or Jmock to assert that an array of java beans has unique property values

Tags: java, junit, jmock

How do i test an array of java beans contains the specified property and the specified valued and that the specified value for the specified property is unique .

Answer (score 1):

This is highly specific functionality, so you'll need to [write a custom Hamcrest `Matcher`](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/wiki/Tutorial) to do it. You can then use this matcher using standard JUnit:

```
Matcher<Object[]> containsTheUniqueProperty(String propName, String propValue) {
    return new Matcher<Object[]>() {
       ...
    }
}
```

---

```
Object[] myArrayOfJavaBeans = ...
assertThat(myArrayOfJavaBeans, containsTheUniqueProperty("prop", "value"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not as elegant, but you could also just iterate over them, keep a set of values, and check each against the set. If any are found, the test fails.